List comprehension vs for loop over same data multiple times (speed-wise)
I know that list comprehension is supposed to be faster as it does less things more effectively but what I measure is contra-intuitive to me.
If I have one big chunk of words:
words = ("Hello. How are you? I am fine. What about you? Me too " * 10_000).split(" ")

and I want to perform some statistic over that list of words - I have two option for-loop and list comprehension:
%%timeit

#1
a = [x for x in words if x.islower()]
>> 3.13 ms ± 802 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

and
a = []
%%timeit
#2
for x in words:
  if x.islower():
    a.append(x)
>> 2.54 ms ± 101 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Which means that comprehension is slower. What I do not understand at all is second example where I need to do multiple tests:
%%timeit

#1
a = [x for x in words if x.islower()]
b = [x for x in words if x.isupper()]
c = [x for x in words if x.istitle()]
d = [x for x in words if x.isalpha()]
e = [x for x in words if x.isnumeric()]
f = [x for x in words if x.isalpha() and x.isupper()]
>> 42.1 ms ± 375 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

and
%%timeit
#2
for x in words:
  if x.islower():
    a.append(x)
  if x.isupper():
    b.append(x)
  if x.istitle():
    c.append(x)
  if x.isalpha():
    d.append(x)
  if x.isnumeric():
    e.append(x)
  if x.isalpha() and x.isupper():
    f.append(x)
>> 70 ms ± 19.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

I thought that having only one for-loop will be more efficient than having multiple list comprehension going over that list over and over again. What is the key to understand this behavior?

I cannot reproduce this with CPython 3.8.1 on Windows 10. The list comprehension takes 8.3 ms while the loop takes 10-11 ms (10.2 with a = [] inside %%timeit). Note a = [] must be inside the %%timeit section or otherwise the list will aggregate all benchmark iterations resulting in slower timings than expected (and not fair with the list comprehension). Same for the second test (47 vs 52 ms -- with all lists created inside the %%timeit). Please report your CPython version, OS, and CPU reference.

The 3rd example should be roughly the same as running the 1st example 6 times, but your timing shows 13 times longer. It seems that there is a major external factor at play.

"3.13 ms ± 802 µs per loop": the implied interval contains the "faster" mean loop time with a much smaller deviation.
